# no existant $(this.el) in backbone view while rendering child view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

full code here... http://pastebin.com/EEnm8vi3

line 378 is not inserting the sections into the current view. **the section model is correctly being passed into the method.** everything else works as expected except for the insertion of the child rendered views.

I am wanting to know why $(this.el) is empty and therefore not allowing an append. trying to use a direct selector like $('#sections') also does not work.

relevent code repeated from pastbin link above: (addOne method)

```
SCC.Views.SectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "div",
    className: "section",
    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        this.template = _.template($('#section-tmpl').html());
    },
    render: function() {
        console.log($(this.el));
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});



SCC.Views.SectionsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "div",
    id: "sections",
    className: "sections",
    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
         //SCC.Sections.bind('add',   this.addOne, this);
         SCC.Sections.bind('reset', this.addAll, this);
         SCC.Sections.bind('all',   this.render, this);
    },
    render: function() {
        $(this.el).html("<p>rendered</p>");
        return this;
    },
    addOne: function(section) {
        var view = new SCC.Views.SectionView({model: section});
        $(this.el).append(view.render().el);
    },
    addAll: function() {
        this.collection.each(this.addOne);
    }

});



SCC.Sections = new SCC.Collections.Sections();
SCC.SectionsView = new SCC.Views.SectionsView({collection:SCC.Sections});
SCC.Sections.reset(window.SectionData);
$('#main').append(SCC.SectionsView.render().el);
```

Comment: Try adding addOne and addAll to the _.bindAll(this, ... ) function. I think why it may be failing it because "this" for addAll is not the BackboneView, until you've bound it.

Comment: i think that did it!!!!! also got rid of `$(this.el).html("<p>rendered</p>");
` which i think helped?

Comment: Instead of writing `$(this.el)`, which means you are casting your element to jQuery many times, you should just use `this.$el`. It's built into Backbone for convenience and efficiency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this problem myself and so I'll leave this answer for anyone else out there:

When you bind this.render to 'all' as @lukemh did:

```
SCC.Sections.bind('all', this.render, this);
```

You're effectively saying everytime an event is triggered in the model/collection re-render the view. When you use *.html()* in that **render** method you're also going to override any child views that may have been *.append()*'ed to it throught the **addOne** function.

If you move the $(this.el).html() call to the initialize view the problem is solved. You can still bind render to 'all' but make sure you're only re-rendering a portion of it or else you'll override the child views again.